Free Space Map details in Postgresql
I figured out how FSM tree constructed on Low level (Inside one page), But idk how different pages works together (I have read all info i could find in the net, including Postgres README).
With have only page for fsm with this data as binary tree:
54
23  54
12 23 54 60
Where 12, 23, 54, 60 are categories of 1, 2, 3, 4 pages respectively.
For simplicity, suppose that one FSM page can store only 4 leaf nodes.
How we will insert into this tree info about next page (5th page)
I tried different variants to figure this out by myself, but it looks weird and supposedly can not be real
